# Greec data export from excel to xml using vba macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'am using a vba macro to export data from an excel file to an xml file.

```
With Worksheets("Worksheet1") 
XMLFileName = "C:\Workspace\Test.xml
idx_string = 1
Open XMLFileName For Output As #1
Print #1, XMLFileHeader
Print #1, "<resources>"
While (.Range("Base_Menue_strings").Cells(idx_string, 1) <> "")
Print #1, " <string name=" & Quotation & .Range("Base_Menue_strings").Cells(idx_string, 1) & Quotation & ">" & Quotation & .Range("Strings").Cells(idx_string, idx_lang) & Quotation & "</string>"
idx_string = idx_string + 1
Wend
Print #1, "</resources>"
Close #1
End With
```

But in the xml file, instead of Greec caracters, I found this:

```
 <resources>
 <string name="dial_mode">"?e?t?????a ???s??"</string>
 <string name="flash_duration">"?????e?a epa?????s??"</string>
 <string name="pabx_title">"????eµa PABX "</string>
 <string name="pabx_status">"?at?stas?"</string>
 </resources>
```

Do anybody know how to solve this ?
Thanks

Comment: do you have the correct language pack installed on the computer that's running the macro?  

Have you set the encoding?

Comment: you should set the encoding for your xml file as UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

I looked [Here](http://forum.fusioncharts.com/topic/3297-greek-characters-not-displaying-correctly-with-setdataurl/) and found out that the XML file needs to be saved as **UTF-8** *with BOM enabled* (byte order mark)
I hope that helps you

Philip

Comment: also look at [Output of XDocument.Save method](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/xmlandnetfx/thread/ccc08c65-01d7-43c6-adf3-1fc70fdb026a)